# Qt c++ json запись в файл

Tags: c++, json, qt, запись

я понял как читать json файлы, но как в них писать?

я пробовал так:

```
 QFile fileJson(":/Json/json/first.json");
 fileJson.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
 fileJson.write("Hello!");
 fileJson.close();
```

но в консоль получил это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

скажите как писать в файлы json с помощью Qt c++!

P.S. в данном примере я просто писал "Hello!", а вы скажите как именно json писать)

```
QVariantMap dict_;
    dict_.insert("level", 3);
    QFile fileJson("./first.json");
    fileJson.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    fileJson.write(QJsonDocument(QJsonObject::fromVariantMap(dict_)).toJson());
    fileJson.close();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

открывается успешно, но не записывает ничего в файл

Comment: что за двоеточие в начале имени файла?  Что вы под этим подразумевали? Одно двоеточие означает, что файл находится в файле ресурсов

Comment: так он там и находится

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того, чтобы записать строку в формате json, следует создать объект класса `QJsonObject`, инициализировать его данными (в моем примере из объекта класса `QVariantMap`, но это необязательно делать именно так), преобразовать в `QByteArray` с помощью `QJsonDocument` и записать эту последовательность байтов в файл, точно так, как вы это делаете в своем примере:

```
 QFile fileJson("./first.json"); //тут я записываю файл в текущей директории

 fileJson.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly); //все верно, если файла нет, он будет создан
 QVariantMap testMap; //тестовые данные, может быть все, что угодно
 testMap.insert("msg", "Hello!");
 testMap.insert("level", 5);
 fileJson.write(QJsonDocument(QJsonObject::fromVariantMap(testMap)).toJson());
 fileJson.close();
```

Как вариант, функцию `toJson` можно вызвать с параметром `QJsonDocument::Compact` (если не требуется "человекочитаемость"):

```
fileJson.write(QJsonDocument(QJsonObject::fromVariantMap(testMap)).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));
```

Результат действия программы (содержимое файла first.json):

```
{
    "level": 5,
    "msg": "Hello!"
}
```

или (при использовании `QJsonDocument::Compact`):

```
{"level":5,"msg":"Hello!"}
```

---

Что же касается файла ресурсов, то данные туда записываются при компиляции проекта, "легальных" способов динамичной записи **Qt** не предоставляет, да я и не вижу в таком хакинге особого смысла, так как для этого существуют прекрасные обычные файлы файловой системы.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102683/discussion-on-answer-by-asianirish-qt-c-json---).

Answer (score 1):

Как вы уже заметили, вы получали ошибку QIODevice::write из-за некорректного открытия файла, так как вы использовали некорректный абсолютный путь к вашему файлу.
Попробуйте использовать QJsonValue вместо QVariantMap, как альтернативный вариант формирования QJsonObject:

```
    QJsonObject jObj;
    jObj.insert("msg", QJsonValue::fromVariant(QVariant("Hello")));
```

Для записи в файл вы можете воспользоваться примером из моей библиотеки [QSerializer](https://github.com/smurfomen/QSerializer):

```
    void writeToJsonFile(QJsonObject jObj)
    {
        QJsonDocument jDoc(jObj);
        QFile file("./first.json");
        if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        {
            file.write(QString(jDoc.toJson()).toStdString().c_str());
            file.close();
        }
    }
```

Mетод QJsonDocument::toJson возвращает QByteArray, остается только обернуть его в QString и получить const char* на данные QString. Однако, обратите внимание, что toJson возвращает JSON в кодировке UTF-8.